# to implement a advanced login functionality help needed

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm developing a system with codeigniter, php and jquery these days, still in the login form, in my login scenario i have a advanced situation i think.

i have different kinds of users in my system,this is a hospital system, first of all there is a person to register people, a person to search old records(files), a person to check eye sight of the people, and a nurse to instruct the patients after they visit the doctor. so i have to give permission to all these people in my system.

now i will tell you about the complication i have, there are 4 doctor units, each separate doctor unit have 2 doctors, a junior one and a senior one. so altogether there are 8 doctors in my system. patients are divided to these 4doctor units, so i have to provide each doctor with a UI that is capable of handling people registered to his or her unit.

as i think form the login if i can redirect the doctors to relevant UI's is will be better. so i need to create a login where a person come enter user name and password, then select the user type, after the selection of that user type, if the user is a doctor ,then another combo box should appear dynamically and he should be given the opportunity to select his relevant doctor unit.

can you guys help me to achieve this functionality?reference links or tutorials to such kind of implementations, instructions about implementing this functionality? all are welcome! :)

regards,
Rangana

Comment: If this is about real life medical data and you are struggling with these (basic) concepts, you should hire someone with the experience to do the security related stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're handling relationships, an [ORM](http://www.overzealous.com/dmz/) will make things easier.

Also, I can't see the reasoning of having a user choose what type of user they are, or even what doctor unit they are in. Can't that just be in the database? When you process the username and password, in that row in the users table, you could have those columns like "user_type".

Answer (score 0):

Why would you make a user select the user type if you have defined your roles in this application. if you store in your user's table a user type field, then when a user logs in, you may know which type of user is and you may redirect him/her properly.

To do this I would recommend using number conventions. For instance user Type 1 is Junior doctor of Unit 1, type 2 is Senior Doctor of Unit 2, and so on...

Also if you use an ORM I'd recommend using either [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) or Doctrine, which are the two most important ORMs in PHP nowadays.

Regards,
DvD

Comment: If the OP sets the user type 1 to be junior doc of unit 1, user type 2 senior of this and that, then he would end up with as many user types as he has users. And then he's back to sorting the users per ID, which is effectively the same as sorting per username, right?